# Group users by another user in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I have this table

[image]

I want to group the collectors and display their borrowers.

**CollectorMember Model**

[image]

**USER CONTROLLER**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::with('collector','borrower','referral')->get();

    return view('dashboard.users.index', compact('users','profile','collector'))
            ->with('collectorBorrowers',$collectorBorrowers);
}
```

**in My Blade**

```
@foreach($collectorBorrowers as $cb)
    <tr>
        {{-- <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td> --}}
        <td>{{ $cb->collector->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $cb->borrower }}</td>
        <td>{{ $cb->referral->code }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Here's the current Output**

[image]

How can I make the output like this

```
Collector 1
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 2 | referralcode
Collector 2
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
Collector 3
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 2 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 3 | referralcode
```

**QUESTION UPDATE**
Following ROMAN BOBRIK's answer

**Now here's my CollectorMembersController looks like,**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::with('collector','borrower','referral')
      ->get()
      ->groupBy('name');

    return view('dashboard.collector-members.index', compact('collectorBorrowers'));
}
```

**By doing this on my blade**

```
@foreach($collectorBorrowers as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item }} ---</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Here's the output**

[image]

On my model I change the hasOne to belongsTo

```
public function collector()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'collector_id','id');
}

public function borrower()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'borrower_id','id');
}

public function referral()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Referral', 'referral_id','id');
}
```

My question is still remain, how can I make the output looks like this,

```
Collector 1
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 2 | referralcode
Collector 2
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
Collector 3
  - borrowerName 1 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 2 | referralcode
  - borrowerName 3 | referralcode
```

**Here's the dd($collectorBorrowers);**

[image]

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: show your current output. i hope you can just group collection after you got data from database

Comment: Hi @RomanBobrik I just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to group collection after you've got data from database:

```php
$collectorBorrowers = CollectorMember::with('collector','borrower','referral')
  ->get()
  ->groupBy('collector.name');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby

Comment: I tried but there's an error says "array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer"

Comment: you have to group collection by string or integer, obviously. in your case you can group it by name of `collector`. so, show your `$collectorBorrowers` dump, then we will be able to understand more clearly

Comment: i meant show your `$collectorBorrowers` dump before you apply grouping. `dump($collectorBorrowers)`

Comment: Hi @Romanbobrik I just added the dd($collectorBorrowers); apology I tried dump($collectorBorrowers); but it disappear and redirecting to the index page.

Comment: so, i updated my answer. try group you data by `collector.name`

Comment: another thing @roman, How can I display them on my index.blade? I tried this,                                     `@foreach($collectorBorrowers as $user) @foreach ($user->collector as $collector){{$collector->name}}@foreach ($user->borrower as $borrower){{$borrower->name}}@endforeach@endforeach@endforeach` but doesn't work.

Comment: The error said, "Property [collector] does not exist on this collection instance."

Answer (score 1):

I might not fully understand what you are trying to do, but to me it seems you could use a better relationship description. Instead of using `hasOne` I would use `belongsToMany` [Laravel # Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Instead of the `CollectorMember` Model you would write the methods to your `User` Model, like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function collector()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'collector_members', 'borrower_id', 'collector_id');
    }

    public function borrower()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'collector_members', 'collector_id', 'borrower_id');
    }
}
```

This way you can do something like this

```
$users = App\User::all();

foreach ($user as $users) {
    foreach ($user->borrower as $borrower) {
        // echo $borrower->name;
        // echo $borrower->pivot->referral_id
    }
}
```

To get access to the referral you can use the pivot method, that gives you access to the intermediate table `collector_members`.

Comment: Thank you so much @wschopohl! this works also! but I will go to romans answer because I am doing showing the data on collectorMembers index and not in Users. But I hope you can show me on how can I implement this on CollectorMembersController. I appreciate your answer so much. thanks again